# Retrofit is not making api call

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 to make api call to my server but it get stucked when trying to make api call. This is my code

```
public interface GOTApi {


    @GET("characters.json")
    Call<GOTCharacterResponse> getCharacters();

}
```

Intermediate class to get the data

```
public class GOTCharacterResponse {

    List<GOTCharacter> characters;
}
```

My class to make api call

```
public class GOTService {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://project-8424324399725905479.firebaseio.com/";

    public static GOTApi getGOTApi(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(GOTApi.class);

    }


    public static void getCharacters(){

        getGOTApi().getCharacters().enqueue(new Callback<GOTCharacterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GOTCharacterResponse> call, Response<GOTCharacterResponse> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GOTCharacterResponse> call, Throwable t) {


                int a = 0;
            }
        });

    }

    }
```

These are the libraries I'm using

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
```

It always get stucked in the getCharacters() method. Of course I have internet permission set in Mainfest.

Comment: What does "get stucked" mean? Crash? or?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash, just the process is not continued, I can't see any warning or error in logcat

Comment: @aloj have you solved your problem ? i'm facing similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Retrofit2 with RxJava, it is more convenient.

```
public Retrofit providedRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

Your API interface will look like

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("api/service/schedule/{filial}")
    Observable<Response<GOTCharacter>>   getSchedule(@Path("some_param")  String param);
}
```

You also need to parse response from JSON. You didn't provided 
GOTCharacter class, but you can create code from json response by using 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ service

Comment: RxJava might indeed be convenient in some cases, but I can't see how adding RxJava support will save OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are implementing wrong `onResponse()` OR `Callback()`, because I am using Retrofit 2 too, in which `onResponse()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<ListJsonResponseRestaurant> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    ...
    ...
}
```